¿Cómo puedo remplazar el id de hilos para que me muestre su nombre en vez de su número asignado?
En clase estoy viendo el tema de hilos y puse en práctica un ejemplo usando semáforos. Mi programa simula un "banco" con solo dos ventanillas y cinco clientes (hilos) que deben esperar su turno para usarlas. Hasta ahí funciona bien pero seguí experimentando y tratando de combinar otros temas que ya he visto anteriormente, como las colecciones.
class WindowAccess implements Runnable{

    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final int id;

    public WindowAccess(Semaphore semaphore, int id){
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { //Tareas del hilo
        try {
            System.out.println("Fulanito: " + id + " está esperando en la fila");
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("Fulanito: " + id + " pasó a la ventanilla");
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
            System.out.println("Fulanito: " + id + " está saliendo de la ventanilla");
            semaphore.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
public class PracticaSemaforo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);

        for(int i = 1 ;i <= 5 ;i++){
            Thread thread = new Thread(new WindowAccess(semaphore, i));
           
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}

Esta es la salida en pantalla:
Fulanito: 4 está esperando en la fila
Fulanito: 3 está esperando en la fila
Fulanito: 2 está esperando en la fila
Fulanito: 3 pasó a la ventanilla
Fulanito: 4 pasó a la ventanilla
Fulanito: 1 está esperando en la fila
Fulanito: 5 está esperando en la fila

Agregué una lista dentro de la clase PracticaSemaforo, pero no se me ocurre cómo hacer para que el resultado en pantalla sea el nombre del cliente en vez del número.
Intente sustituyendo el for de esta forma: for(int i = 0 ;i <= fulanitos.size() ;i++){}
pero aun así me sigue mostrando números del 1 al 5 y no los nombres contenidos en la lista.
public static List<String> fulanitos = Arrays.asList("Jorgito", "Miu", "Baguira", "Ranito","Polita");


Probaste de cambiar el tipo int por String? O podrías usar thread.setName("Nombre")

En el constructor de WindowAccess, pasa el nombre en vez del ID. Modifica el código así:

Cambia el parámetro int id por String name en WindowAccess.
En el for, pasa los nombres de la lista fulanitos.

Corregido, esto mostrará los nombres en vez de los números:
class WindowAccess implements Runnable{

private final Semaphore semaphore;
private final String name;

public WindowAccess(Semaphore semaphore, String name){
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(name + " está esperando en la fila");
        semaphore.acquire();
        System.out.println(name + " pasó a la ventanilla");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(name + " está saliendo de la ventanilla");
        semaphore.release();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
}

public class PracticaSemaforo {

public static List<String> fulanitos = Arrays.asList("Jorgito", "Miu", "Baguira", "Ranito", "Polita");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);

    for(String fulanito : fulanitos){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new WindowAccess(semaphore, fulanito));
        thread.start();
    }
}
}


Muchas gracias:)
